# R mediation package output: independent variable effect on mediators

Tags: r, mediation

I’m a phd student struggling with mediation package.
Is there anyway I can get direct effect of independent variable on all mediators and that of mediators on dependent variable with this package?

ACME and ADE are awesome but I need those direct effects as well.
Thank you!!

Comment: Is the ADE not the direct effect?

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply! I understand that ADE is the direct effect of independent var on dependent var. I want to measure direct effect of independent var on mediators and that of mediators on dependent var. Please correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: Oh, aren't those in the regressions you supplied to to `mediate()`? The mediator regression is the regression of the mediator on the focal predictor and confounders and the outcome regression is the regression of the outcome on the mediator, focal predictor, and confounders. I guess I'm not clear on what you want that you don't have.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Oh I didn’t supply regression but only supplied the vectors of character strings for treatment, mediators, and outcome as well as a name of data frame as required by « mediations () » function. I guess the process is different for multiple mediations.